# Inner page not found apache2 how to fix?

Tags: php, apache

Make this

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Also change this in apache2.conf file located at /etc/apache2

```
nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Finally Restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**But after this i got 500 at any page, how to fix?**

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# The Friendly URLs part
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/{2,} [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [R=301,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
AddEncoding gzip .jgz


Header append Vary Accept env=REDIRECT_accept

AddType image/webp .webp


ExpiresActive On
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such errors need to watch in logs by this address `/var/log/apach2`
In error log I found that I used **some var** in `.htaccess` and my server doesn't support it, but the default

```
$ sudo a2enmod headers
$ sudo a2enmod expires
$ systemctl restart apache2
```

Fix this.